# clone sda into sdb with Python

Tags: python

Can I clone `sda` to `sdb` with this Python program?

```
filein = open('/dev/sda', 'rb')  
fileout = open('/dev/sdb', 'wb')  

while True:  
   tmp = filein.read(100000)  
   fileout.write(tmp)  

filein.close()
fileout.close()
```

Comment: To the 'close' voters: I think the question is legitimate: could `dd` be implemented in python? Or is there some more filesystem foo required to create a real disk clone?

Comment: Please tell us what do _you_ think? What have you tried?

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry in its current form the question is about whether or not the specific Python code would do such thing, not whether it would be possible, and if so how. This question currently is neither helpful nor does it show any research effort by the OP, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script will not work entirely, no.  For instance, how will you exit from the loop on EOF?

But more to the point, why use Python for this task?  Why not `dd`?  It already handles all the cases you would need to deal with for this task.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1024k
```

(Substitute your favorite blocksize for `1024k`.)